# Refreshing the ribbon interface after a call from a macro in an excel sheet

Tags: vsto, ms-office, excel-2007

Here is my scenario:

- I have an old excel project with macros that I've imported in a vsto project.
- I have designed a custom ribbon (`startFromScratch = true`) to make it look like a dictator application.
- I still want to use the existing macro code since it would take too much time to translate all the vba code in c# code
- I have a class that is marked with the `[ComVisible(true)]` attribute so that I can call vsto methods from the vba code.

The problem is that I can't hide tabs, I can't get the ribbon to refresh. I can change the state of other controls (e.g. set checked state for CheckBox), but I can't hide or disable my custom tabs.

I have tried `PerformLayout()`, `PerformDynamicLayout()` on the ribbon, `ribbon.RibbonUI.Invalidate()`, but nothing works, the tab never changes state, although in code I set its visible property to `false`.

What do I need to do in order to refresh the ribbon at runtime?

---

**Edit:**

I just tried the same thing by exporting the ribbon to xml and the `Invalidate()` method works as expected. Is there any way to accomplish this for a ribbon designed with the visual editor?

Comment: Could you post some code that shows how you set the tab's `Visible` property to `false`?

Comment: Well, the tab is a RibbonTab control, so I just set its Visible property to false (myTab.Visible = false). There is no problem setting it, if I am debugging I can see the property being set to false, the problem is that the ribbon itself won't refresh.
If I use the xml ribbon, I can call its Invalidate() method, but there's no such method for the ribbon designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replicated your problem when I set the `StartFromScratch` property of the ribbon to `True`, but it goes away when I set it to `False`. This is [confirmed by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.officeribbon.startfromscratch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> You cannot change the visibility of custom tabs at run time if this property is set to true.

As a workaround, set `StartFromScratch` to `False`, add in a tab for each default tab, setting the `ControlIdType` of each to `Office` and the `OfficeId` of each to their default name (`TabHome`, `TabFormulas`, etc.), then set each of these built-in tab's visibility to `False`. ([MSDN has made available a full list of control IDs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3582) for their Office apps for easy reference.)

Comment: Damn, I missed that Remarks section in the StartFromScratch MSDN article :)
Thanks a lot for your solution.